# npm peerDependencies during development

Tags: node.js, npm

**Setup:**

Package `models`

- Common mongoose models used across multiple apps
- peerDependencies: "mongoose"

Package `app`

- dependencies: "mongoose", "models"
- Linked with models through `app> npm link models`

**Issue:**

When developing `models`, I need mongoose installed under `node_modules`, otherwise it can't find mongoose.

However, when using `models` under `app`, if mongoose exists under `node_modules` in `models`, it uses that copy instead of sharing the same instance of mongoose with `app`.

The way I'm making this work now is installing mongoose when developing `models`, then deleting it when using it under `app`. I've looked into `parent-require` but this seems to only solve the issue with npm link not finding the package from the parent, not the issue with having to remove/install the node_module (or am I doing this incorrectly?)

Related:
[Sharing a Mongoose instance between multiple NPM packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754604/sharing-a-mongoose-instance-between-multiple-npm-packages)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've taken to using `require.main.require` instead of `require` for modules that need a shared instance.

For example, `require.main.require('mongoose')` will guarantee only the top-level mongoose is used.

Comment: For those coming here from Google, there is potential good news. [Node v6 may finally include a patch for this bug.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/5950#issuecomment-213053455).

Answer (score 0):

In case you get an error

```
require.main.require is not supported by webpack
```

... call `npm link <required module>` in your module's root dir

E.g. I had the same issue with *peerDependency* **react**. So I did `npm link reack` for my local module and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a module that you can use that deals with parent and grandparent modules that are linked

```
/**
 * the original module scope
 */
const _BASE_MODULE = module;

/**
 * the top level module (fixes nasty peer dependency issues with npm link)
 */
const _MODULE = topLevelModule();

/**
 * find topmost module scope
 */
function topLevelModule() {
    let _mod = _BASE_MODULE;

    while (_mod.parent) {
        _mod = _mod.parent;
    }

    return _mod;
}

/**
 * cheap way to check if the module is available,
 *
 * @param {string} mod module name
 * @return {boolean}
 * @todo if we need better then we should switch to browserifys resolve package, but thats heavy
 */
export function isAvailable(mod) {
    try {
        _MODULE.require.resolve(mod);

        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * requires a module from the top level scope
 * @param {string } mod module name
 * @return {*}
 */
export function topLevelRequire(mod) {
    return _MODULE.require(mod);
}
```