# How to test an npm module with peerDependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, gulp-mocha, peer-dependencies

I am new to understand **peerDependencies**, and I have read the following references seeking as to how to test an npm module contains peerDependencies within its package.json:

- [Peer Dependencies](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/)
- [Understanding the npm dependency model](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2016/08/24/understanding-the-npm-dependency-model/)
- [Common npm mistakes](https://medium.com/@jacob.h.page/common-npm-mistakes-51bf8989079f)
- [StackOverflow: npm peerDependencies during development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684309/npm-peerdependencies-during-development)

However, I have not found a clear solution for testing npm with peerDependencies. Some recommend adding the peerDependencies as globals, and some reference to include peerDependencies within devDependencies, and neither seems right.

For example, I have a package that has a peer dependency, a custom logger, and this logger needs to be **configured by its host package** before it can be used.

This is how I perform most tests scripted in using this Gulp task:

```
function testRunner() {
  return (
    gulp
      .src('./tests/**/*.js', { read: false })
      .pipe(
        mocha({
          exit: true,
          timeout: 10000
        })
      )
      .on('error', console.error)
  );
}
```

I did receive a helpful suggestion (see comments below, @estus) to use [**npm-install-peers**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-peers), however, I am not yet certain if it can configure a peer dependency before usage, as it would be performed by the host package.

Feedback and Suggestions are most appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'testing'? Are you looking to write automated tests? Are you talking about manually testing something? Are you talking about something else?

Comment: @pedro-a Thank you for your response, I appreciate that I should add clarity as to what I mean by "testing". I have just edited my question with Gulp task that performs a mocha test. So, what I mean by testing is first localized followed by CI automated tests.

Comment: Possibly https://github.com/spatie/npm-install-peers

Comment: @estus Thank you for your suggestion, I am checking it out now and connecting with its author. I forgot one detail, the peer dependency also needs to be configured by the peer's parent. Adding that detail to my initial question.

Comment: I am currently checking out another npm package: [npm install-peerdeps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-peerdeps)

Comment: One of the authors of npm-install-peers is provided an answer below.

Comment: I case you are asking yourself how to test multiple version of a peer dependency, it's explained [in this article](https://dev.to/joshx/test-your-npm-package-against-multiple-versions-of-its-peer-dependency-34j4), TLDR: You can explicitly install different versions of a package by using `"dep-v1": "npm:dep@1", "dep": "2"` in your `devDependencies`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In my case, I developed a library last time that use `ioredis` as peer dependency. My solution was to put that library as well in dev dependency.

```
// package.json
"peerDependencies": {
    "ioredis": "4.x"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "ioredis": "4.x"
}
```

it worked well and no issue so far using this approach.

Comment: Also, to test your package on different peer versions, you can temporarily change that dev dependency to specific versions, re-install dependencies (I use `npm ci`), and run your tests.

Answer (score 8):

I had connected with the authors of npm-install-peers, and the response from one of the authors,

> When it comes to testing your package/project on CI, I believe the
>   correct way to do things is manually adding your peer dependencies to
>   your dev dependencies. No need for this little tool.

Comment: I added the same devDependency as is in my peerDependencies so that my unit tests run. These seems like the most appropriate way to do this.