# Why does Jest fail to run tests that reference npm packages?

Tags: reactjs, npm, jestjs

I created a new project with [create-react-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library). I am trying to add a unit test using Jest and Enzyme. My test works for a simple component, but Jest fails to test a component that references [semantic-ui-react](https://react.semantic-ui.com/).

This test works:

```
// src/VanillaComponent.test.js
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const VanillaComponent = () => <div>Test</div>;

test('Enzyme can render a vanilla component', () => {
  expect(shallow(<VanillaComponent />)).toBeDefined();
});
```

This test does **not** work:

```
// src/SemanticComponent.test.js
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const SemanticComponent = () => <Button>Test</Button>;

test('Enzyme can render a semantic-ui-react component', () => {
  expect(shallow(<SemanticComponent />)).toBeDefined();
});
```

When I run `npm test` on the test above, I get the following error:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'semantic-ui-react' from 'SemanticComponent.test.js'

   > 4 | import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
        | ^
```

Relevant parts of `package.json` file (lots of unrelated content removed):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "run-s test:unit test:lint test:build",
    "test:build": "run-s build",
    "test:lint": "eslint .",
    "test:unit": "cross-env CI=1 react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "test:watch": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1"
  },
}
```

How can I get this second test to run? Am I missing some Jest configuration?

Comment: Just had to look up `create-react-library` and see it is for creating libraries, so then I thought, yeah, maybe `semantic-ui` isn't installed where the test is running and wanted to ask to see your package.json file and see it is listed as peer dependency as opposed to a regular or dev dependency. It may need to also be a regular dependency.

Comment: I observed the same behavior with `create-react-app`. (I discovered that after my original post, otherwise I would have referenced CRA since that is more commonly-used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I referenced `semantic-ui-react` as a peer dependency in the `package.json` file. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54305746/11838196) which led me to add `semantic-ui-react` as both a peer dependency and a dev dependency. After making that change, the test works fine.

This solution does not feel super clean to me, but I don't anticipate any problems, so I will go with this approach for now.