# GruntJS/NPM package.json : installing from local?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

With GruntJS/NPM package.json

If I've cloned an module from github to local, how can I reference that in my package.json so it installs from the local version?

Comment: I found this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575627/can-you-host-a-private-repository-for-your-organization-to-use-with-npm

Except it seems too much. I just want to point to a cloned git directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a forked version of the original repo on Github, and reference [your Github URL in `package.json`](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#Git-URLs-as-Dependencies). You can even specify a branch or tag while you wait for upstream to accept any patches you may have.

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-task": "git://github.com/username/repo.git#branch"
}
```

Or, you can use [`npm link`](https://npmjs.org/doc/link.html) to reference a project located on your hard drive. This works fine if you're the only developer, but deployment will be a bit more tricky regardless. (the option above is byfar the best one)

Comment: Thanks for this, seems to be the best option.