# Sharing files among multiple nodejs projects

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I've been tasked with refactoring the React UI in a project that has two nodejs projects in it (both with React).  Currently both nodejs projects have the same UI components.  My question is, is there a way to move the common components to a shared folder outside of the nodejs project folder?

> |-- Main Project
>
> > |-- Nodejs Project1
> >
> > |-- Nodejs Project2
> >
> > |-- Common Folder  <--- *Move Common Components Here*

I've tried referencing the files through relative and direct paths, but node seems to freak out whenever I try to access anything outside of it project folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461465/sharing-code-between-node-applications

Comment: It's just a matter of using the correct relative paths.  Files are just files to node.js so you just need a correct path to the file.  We can't really help any more specifically than that because you've offered no specific details.