# What is the node repository equivalent of artifactory for maven?

Tags: node.js, maven, module, artifactory

We'd like to use Node on our build server but would prefer to archive modules in a repository. (As we do with maven and artifactory.)

My question is: **What is the node repository equivalent of artifactory for maven?**

Comment: You are talking about a Node on Jenkins ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7575627/1700321.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Artifactory also support hosting [NPM](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Repositories) repositories. Artifactory support for npm provides:

1. The ability to provision npm packages from Artifactory to the npm command line tool from all repository types
2. Calculation of Metadata for npm packages hosted in Artifactory's local repositories
3. Access to remote npm registries (such as https://registry.npmjs.org)
   through Remote Repositories which provide the usual proxy and
   caching functionality
4. The ability to access multiple npm registries from a single URL by
       aggregating them under a Virtual Repository. This overcomes the
       limitation of the npm client which can only access a single registry
       at a time.
5. Compatibility with the npm command line tool to deploy and remove
   packages and more.
6. Support for flexible npm repository layouts that allow you to
   organize your npm packages and assign access privileges according to
       projects or development teams.

Answer (score 0):

A good article at : https://blog.theodo.com/2016/01/speed-up-npm-install-with-a-nexus-proxy-to-cache-packages/

It mention the Nexus can do it. There is a free and open source version of Nexus Repository at https://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype. It can support Maven, NPM and many other repositories types.