# Install node extensions without commands

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am doing an internship in a company.
I need to create a node server.
I installed node on the computer (Windows) and I should install some plugins like:
   - nodejs-webpack
   - colors
   - uglify

Normally I need to enter a command like : `npm install "theModule"`
But the software can not access the internet (due to company restrictions) and support service can not authorize the software (or do not want).

Can I install modules in any other way ? (download from Google and slide archives in the correct folder for example).

---

If the answer is no, do you know how can i get around this security?

Answer (score 5):

You need a private npm repository.

Check out this answer:

[can you host a private repository for your organization to use with npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575627/can-you-host-a-private-repository-for-your-organization-to-use-with-npm)

Comment: Ok thanks, so a private npm repository works like a repository in Cydia ? It will purpose me an alternative "market" with some node's extensions right ?

Comment: This might not work as you still need to use commands like `npm install couchapp` and `npm install semver`.

Answer (score 2):

I found it !
Just for exemple, we will install 'nodejs-websocket' :
1) You just have to download it [here](https://github.com/sitegui/nodejs-websocket).
2) Put files into your Node's directory (for me it's "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules")
3) in your .js file just add this line : `var ws = require("C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nodejs-websocket/")`
Done ! Thanks for all :D

Comment: Good work, This is showing alternative for command line installation. But manual effort may leads to human errors most of the cases...

Comment: This means you'll have to check in the `node_modules` folder which is what we did on our project, but it's a hell to upgrade your dependencies afterwards

Comment: You did everything mostly right, but instead of dropping your module in your global `node_modules` directory, you should copy it into a `node_modules` directory in the root of your project. Then you can simply do `var ws = require("nodejs-websocket");` When you do `npm install package-name` normally, that's where it puts it. Where you put it is where npm would put the module if you did `npm install -g package-name`, which is usually for installing command line tools, not modules your app will consume in code.

Answer (score 0):

I added this as a comment on your own answer, but I figured I should add a real answer with a better explanation.

Normally when you run `npm install package-name` npm installs the package to a `node_modules` directory in the directory you are in at that moment. So if your app was located at `C:\code\my-app` then you would `cd` into that directory and run `npm install package-name`. This would create a `node_modules` directory at `C:\code\my-app\node_modules` if it didn't already exist. Then it would install `package-name` into that directory at `C:\code\my-app\node_modules\package-name`.

As long as the module is in the `node_modules` directory for your app, you can require the module in your code without entering a big long file path.

```
var ws = require('nodejs-websocket');
```

The place you manually installed your module is the global `node_modules` directory. It's where npm would install a module if you did `npm install -g package-name`. The global `node_modules` directory is added to your system path when you install npm. In other words, any modules you install in there would be accessible from the command line like any other command. For example:

```
npm install -g bower
```

That would install the "bower" package to the global npm module directory. Bower would then be accessible as a command line tool for you to use. For example:

```
bower install angularjs
```

The global directory is more for tools like that and not really for modules that you intend to use in your code. Technically you can require a module from anywhere by including the full path in the `require` call like you did, but the standard practice would be to place it in the `node_modules` directory in the root of your application, and then require it with just its name and not a full path.

---

**Edit:** Here's another tip that you might like to take advantage of as well.

When you normally install a module with `npm install package-name`, your application usually has a `package.json` file at the root of it. If it does, you can do `npm install package-name --save` and npm will add the `package-name` module to a list in your app's `package.json` file. Once a module is listed in your app's `package.json` file it's called a "dependency" of your app because it basically says your app *depends* on `package-name`.

Normally, when you have dependencies listed in `package.json`, you can completely delete your app's `node_modules` directory and then simply run `npm install` from within your app's root directory and npm will automatically install all dependencies it finds listed in your app's `package.json` file. Since your corporate firewall won't allow this automatic downloading of modules, you won't get that benefit. However it is still good practice to follow the same conventions.

A trick you can do to create your `package.json` file is to manually install your dependencies into your app's `node_modules` directory. Once you have the modules your app needs, you can instruct npm to create a `package.json` file for your app by simply running `npm init`. It will walk you through a few little prompts to fill out your `package.json` file with details about your app. It will then peek inside your `node_modules` directory to see if you've already installed any modules before having a `package.json` file. If it finds any, it will automatically add them to the dependencies field in the `package.json` file it creates :D

With a proper `package.json` in place you'll always have a nice tidy list of what dependencies your application needs, even if your `node_modules` directory gets deleted. Normally people add their app's `node_modules` directory to their `.gitignore` file, only checking in the `package.json` file. This way they don't store their dependencies in source control but they can still be easily installed on new machines that clone it by simply running `npm install` from inside the app's directory. In your case though you may want to just add `node_modules` to your source control since you can't let npm install dependencies automatically.