# How to use multiple nested private node modules?

Tags: node.js, git, github, node-modules

The following is my project structure

```
Base Application
  |
  |----Node Module 1 
  |       |
  |       |----Node Module 2
  |
  |----Node Module 2
```

All these are private repositories. I added the following in the base application's `package.json`

```
{
name: "Base Application",
  dependencies: {
  ..
  node-module1: "git+https://github.com/abc/node-module1.git",
  node-module2: "git+https://github.com/abc/node-module2.git",
  ..
  }
}
```

I cloned my repository using `HTTPS` version (https://github.com/abc/base-application.git) which prompts me for username and password. Once cloned, when I tried to do a `npm install`, I was getting the following error

```
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository '/home/ubuntu/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-github-com-abc-node-module1-git-3bd17fdf3s45ae0sdfadf68sdegk72e3'...
npm ERR! remote: Invalid username or password.
npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/abc/node-module1.git/'
```

After some digging, I modified my `package.json` to include version as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7807279/826610).

```
{
name: "Base Application",
  dependencies: {
  ..
  node-module1: "git+https://github.com/abc/node-module1.git#v0.0.1",
  node-module2: "git+https://github.com/abc/node-module2.git#v0.0.1",
  ..
  }
}
```

This works. But the problem is I am been prompted for the username and password **multiple times**. This will also create the complexity of creating a version in the node-modules every time a minute change is made.

So how can I use private node modules as how we use public ones.

Comment: Try to clone with http and not https. https require username password so you will have to pass or store them for the clonning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you identify yourself in `package.json`, as described in "[How to use private Github repo as npm dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28729646/6309)"

> **https and oauth**: [create an access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/) that has "repo" scope and then use this syntax:

```
"package-name": "git+https://<github_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git"
```

That way, `npm install` should have access to those private repo without asking again for credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the version, you can also reference a specific branch such as master, so that you don't need to bump the version for every commit.

```
"node-module1": "git://github.com/abc/node-module1.git#master"
```

However, I'd recommend sticking with [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), and consider setting up your own private NPM repository such as https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia. To test a module that's under development inside another module/app, you can use `npm link`, and then publish the versioned module when done, always bumping the major version whenever you make API-incompatible changes.