# Adding new users to an npm-organization via cmd line

Tags: npm

Is adding new users to an npm organization via cmd line an option? I checked out their docs and google, and could only find a way to add users through the npmjs.com dashboard.

I want to create an app in which devs from my org can register without me having to register them by hand, one by one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can you host a private repository for your organization to use with npm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575627/can-you-host-a-private-repository-for-your-organization-to-use-with-npm)

Comment: Nope, I'm talking about this - https://docs.npmjs.com/orgs/what-are-orgs and how I can add new members to the organisation I've created, using command line. The only answer I've found is "To add a member to your organization, you add them by their npm username via the Organization Dashboard." (https://docs.npmjs.com/orgs/setup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who ever asks the same question - I got an answer from npm support:

> Currently, the super-admin of the organization will need to use the organization's dashboard via the website.

In other words, the answer to my question is no. Adding a new user to an npm org is not possible via command line (or any other API for that matter).