# Is there a way to force npm install all dependencies from intranet location

Tags: node.js, npm

Let's assume that I have a directory in my intranet, which contains a node_modules folder, which contains all the dependencies, which I need for my web-project to work. As far as I know, I can type something like (in the terminal from my project's root folder):

```
npm i "\\RepoComp\Repo\node_modules\bootstrap"
```

So, it will install `bootstrap` package into my project. It's quite good, but I wouldn't like to install all of the packages, listed in my `package.json` manually, I'd like to type just:

```
npm i <path-to-intranet-repo>
```

And I expect npm to gather all of the dependencies from this intranet location. How can I achieve this?

**PS:** Actually, what I try to achieve - is placing all dependencies to remote folder in intranet location, so all the developers in my team can access needed packages from there, without internet connection. Is it possible? However, as I found from npm-debug.log, it attempts to connect to registry.npmjs.org, while trying to install packages through `npm --prefix "\\RepoComp\Repo\node_modules\" install` command.

Comment: What you're looking for is a *private* NPM repository. Please see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7575627/272735 that addresses your root problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can you host a private repository for your organization to use with npm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575627/can-you-host-a-private-repository-for-your-organization-to-use-with-npm)

Comment: @user272735, doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch from `npm` to `yarn` and use it's offline-mirror feature. see [Running Yarn offline](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `npm install <folder>` variant with the `--prefix` option.

```
npm --prefix ./path-to-intranet install
```

References:

- [prefix](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prefix)
- [install folder variant](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)
- [Some more information](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#more-information)

You could also try:

`(cd intranet-location && npm install)`

Comment: `npm --prefix "\\RepoComp\Repo\node_modules\" install` causes "error parsing json" during "angular" dependency installation

Comment: it also says: `npm ERR! failed to fetch from registry: https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fanimations`

Comment: Did it install other modules?

Comment: No, "node_modules" folder doesn't even appear in projects root folder.

Comment: Why did you do `npm --prefix "\\RepoComp\Repo\node_modules\`? You need to give the path till `Repo`

Comment: What do you mean as "path till"?  `"\\RepoComp\Repo\node_modules"` is actual path to my repo. Am I wrong?

Comment: Doesn't the project's `package.json` reside inside `Repo`? We need to send  `npm --prefix "\\RepoComp\Repo\" install` as the command

Comment: Doesn't seem to work even after placing package.json to remote folder. Actually, what I try to achieve - is placing all dependencies to remote folder in intranet location, so all the developers in my team can access needed packages from there, without internet connection. Is it possible? However, as I found from `npm-debug.log`, it attempts to connect to registry.npmjs.org, while trying to install packages.

Comment: You also said to try `(cd intranet-location && npm install)` but it seems to install packages into remote folder, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in which platform you are working in.

But assuming you are working in some LINUX virtual machine (like putty or something). I think you just need to export the path of the correct npm path which is using this node_modules.

```
$bash
$export PATH=/path/to/the/dir:$PATH
```

For other cases around, use the 'prefix' config defaults to the location where node is installed. On most systems, this is /usr/local. On windows, this is the exact location of the node.exe binary.

For more guidance: [refer to this doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders)

Comment: actually, I'm using windows 10, but, anyway it doesn't seem to have any sense for me, what you just wrote.

Comment: Modified as per your requirement.