# Publish the React JS Component internally within the Organization

Tags: reactjs, npm

[image: React JS Folder Structure]

We have created the Table Component in React JS. Now we are planning to publish this component in other projects

Can you please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: This question may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575627/can-you-host-a-private-repository-for-your-organization-to-use-with-npm

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of information about how to publish a ReactJS component in this link: https://medium.com/@BrodaNoel/how-to-create-a-react-component-and-publish-it-in-npm-668ad7d363ce

Did you read it?