# How to implement GrapesJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, grapesjs

Anyone suggest me or give me proper guide of implementing in my local. 
this is a [guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grapesjs) 
but i want some more clear guide. because this guide to i am not understanding.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grapesjs

Comment: did you integrate it on your server? The guide on [github](https://github.com/artf/grapesjs) is pretty much straightforward. You download the sources from one of the sites mentioned under download. Then you build it up they way you want as descriped on [GrapJS.com](https://grapesjs.com/docs/getting-started.html#import-the-library). You can do it via npm as well, as described in the ansswer below. If you an npm instances running it is even easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do two things:
1. Use your command prompt, You need to have **node** and **npm** latest stable versions installed. Navigate into your folder directory where your project is and run `npm i grapesjs` wait for a while and then a `package.json` file should be created check it to see if `grapesjs` is there then require it in wherever you want to use it.

2. Go to `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/grapesjs/0.12.17/grapes.min.js` and `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/grapesjs/0.12.17/css/grapes.min.css` download the source code. Link both the `css` and `j`s files in your index file or where you want to use it. Then go to their documentation site `https://github.com/artf/grapesjs/wiki` try out an example to see if everything checks out fine

Comment: could you explain how to host an own npm on a private server but using repos hosted on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/). I found several tutorials but it seems there isn't a standard procedure. That is what I found: [sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia), [host a private repository ... to use with npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575627/can-you-host-a-private-repository-for-your-organization-to-use-with-npm)  and [Host your own private NPM repository with Verdaccio](https://medium.com/devopslinks/host-your-own-private-npm-repository-with-verdaccio-e8a3202b97c5)

Comment: sorry I haven't seen the wood for the trees, [npm is installed with Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm)