# How to create NPM scoped packages with git

Tags: git, npm, ssh, scope

I would like to create scoped packages without paying for npm private registry.
I have a private git repository (accessible with ssh) but there is no documentation on how to do this and with which syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your own private registry. See for example: [npm Registry for your organisation](https://medium.com/@ayusharma.in/npm-registry-for-your-organisation-aeb8ea76144).

Then as described in the [npm scope documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scope#associating-a-scope-with-a-registry)

> You can associate a scope with a registry at login, e.g.
>
> ```
> npm login --registry=http://reg.example.com --scope=@myco
> ```

or

> You can also associate a scope with a registry using npm config:
>
> ```
> npm config set @myco:registry http://reg.example.com
> ```

Comment: I want to use git or gitlab or something like this without hosting it

Comment: Yes, you can either use the [Gitlab packages registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/) or use a [raw git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7807279/1807667).