# Will the composer update command overwrite changed files

Tags: composer-php

I have a project for which I used `composer install` to download all of the dependancies I need.  In order for one of those dependencies to work for my project, I had to make a few small changes to some of its class files.

If I run `composer update` again for my project, does that mean composer will re-download the original version of that package, therefore overwriting the customizations I previously made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if there are updates to the original package, composer will overwrite your changes. I suggest forking the dependency and telling composer to use your fork instead.

```json
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/the-package": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/flyingl123/the-package.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can find more instructions about [forking a package](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository) in the composer docs.

Comment: it is possible to [fork in a private repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137997/forking-from-github-to-bitbucket) in case the changes you need to do are to be private, ie contain business logic or business-related informations. the procedure is also explained in the link on forking a package.