# How to organise Git workflow for small codes from school

Tags: git, github, workflow, code-organization, fork

anyone have better idea to organise my small codes from school then using Github and create one repository for every programming language? I would like to create repository for every small code, but I think thats wasting of time. Because I want to sync these codes with my second computer and If I create repository for every small code I will have to use Pull many times.

But on the other hands I want to use Branches, Forking etc.

Thank you!

Comment: what's wrong with only create one repo for all codes and put them to different folder?

Comment: Maybe if I fork it, I will fork all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you put codes on github, is you want it be forked. So only put the worth-forking codes there. Other code you can use git to set up local repo for version control.

And [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-you-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository) may help you.

You can repo all your codes in one local git repo, and create submodules for github repo?