# Git add branch on one single directory?

Tags: git, github, branch

I have a git repository on GitHub, with 3 different folders and only the master branch. How can i create a new branch on one single directory instead of all the three?

Comment: Why not create a branch and only modify files in that directory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't.  Git operates on the entire repository, not on individual directories.  You can:

- Create a new branch, and on that branch only modify things in your target directory.
- You could obviously follow william.eyidi's suggestion and delete the other directories, but this will make things difficult if you want to merge changes back into your master branch.
- You could set up the specific directory as a git submodule with it's own history separate from the parent repository, but this is probably more complex than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should delete that repository and do it again, but this time with the right branch.

You mentioned you have 3 folders, but you want to versionize just one folder. So go to your folder with git.

This is an example in a Git-Bash

```
cd /path/to/your/folder
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "My first commit."
git push origin master
```

Origin has to be the github-repository address.

Answer (score 0):

1. git checkout -b
2. delete localy the 2 others directories
3. git push

Answer (score 0):

After creating a new branch, instead of checking out the branch for the entire repository, you can have add directory that tracks this branch while the other directories are tracking an other branch.

```
git worktree add masterBranchDirectory master
```

Now the directory masterBranchDirectory is a copy of the entire repository. After changing into this directory you are automatically on master branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new repository for the single folder within your surrounding project.

e.g. for a project named **App**:

lets say within your **App** project you want **folder1** to be your new Repo.
You wold have to create a new Repo on your github. And then inside your local **App** open git bash:

```
# create a Git Repository:

$ cd /folder1
$ git init -b main
$ git add . && git commit -m "initial commit"  

# link local Repo with remote Repo:

$ git remote add origin  <REMOTE_URL TO NEWLY CREATED REPO> 
# Sets the new remote
$ git remote -v
# Verifies the new remote URL  

# push your new Repo to Github:

$ git push origin main
```

**then**
if your **App** project was your whole developement folder
and **folder1** was your distribution folder, where the build files were in

you could always just clone **folder1's** Repo for presentation purposes

and the **App Repo** for developement purposes.

Also basically you have a seperate branch for your single folder just inside a different Repository.
But since its within your **App** it makes no difference.

Option B:

Also there is the Option of **git submodules** as mentioned in previous posts.
Where you could have **foler1** even separatley (but not necessarily seperate) from your main Repo and only "embed" it into your **App**.
https://git-scm.com/book/de/v2/Git-Tools-Submodule
[How do I work with a git repository within another repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30938252)