# How to handle nested git repositories?

Tags: git, heroku

I have a new project where the entire thing is under version control.

The projects directory looks like this:

```
/projectname
--/web
   --nodeapp.js
--/mobile
   --androidapp
```

So currently, .git is in the root of the project in `/projectname`. Is it possible to also put the two subdirectories into their own repo? For example, the `/web` directory contains a node app that will be deployed via Heroku, and Heroku deployments use git to deploy, so i need that part to be its own repo as obviously deploying the entire project (android included) to Heroku would be silly.

I *think* i've read submodules may be good for this use case, but i'm not quite sure if thats correct and if it is how to use them in my case. Thanks!

Comment: duplicate: [How do I work with a git repository within another repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to also put the two subdirectories into their own repo?

Yes.  That's exactly what a submodule is.  What happens when you do that is, `git add` of the subdirectory stores the id of the currently-checked-out commit in that directory.

You don't need to use the `git submodule` command.  There are tasks it does  that often need doing, but they're obvious ones, and really almost all of them are straightforward oneliners -- and the ones that aren't, aren't much harder than that.  The most useful thing the submodule command does is hoist the actual repository out of the subdirectory and into a handy (and arbitrary) nook in the existing repo, so you can still nuke your worktree with impunity.

---

Here's how you find all your currently-tracked submodules, regardless of whether you've told the submodule command about them:

```
git ls-files -s|grep ^16            # ls-files -s output: mode id stage path
```

All the submodules in a commit, regardless of whether you've told the submodule command about them:

```
git ls-tree -r $id|grep ^16         # ls-tree -r output:  mode type id path
```

(`$id` can be e.g. just `master`, or `@` a.k.a. `HEAD`)

Id the tracked state for a submodule

```
git rev-parse :path/to/it           # from index i.e. last add/checkout/reset/etc 
git rev-parse $id:path/to/it        # from $id, e.g. `master` or `3fac3`
```

Find out what's currently checked out in a submodule:

```
(cd "$submodule"; git rev-parse HEAD)
```

Check out the right commit in a submodule:

```
(id=`git rev-parse :"$submodule"` && cd "$submodule" && git checkout $id)
```

... and so forth.

So, what is the submodule command really doing for you?  Aside from the hoisting above, the only thing it <s>does</s>adds is a handy place to keep notes -- for instance, where's the default spot to find those commits?  The `git submodule` command has settled on `.gitmodules` as a good place to store stuff like this.  As with all things git, the only thing that matters is the commits. Everything else, `.gitmodules` file included, is just handy-but-dispensable notes.

Answer (score 2):

I find a `git subtree` is simpler to learn how to use than the `submodule`. This tends to be easier to share with team collaborators instead of dealing with sub modules.

First add the remote for `web`

```
git remote add weborigin https://path.to/remotes/plugin.git
```

create subtree specifying the new folder prefix

`weborigin` is the remote name, and `master` refers to the `master` branch on the subtree's repository. `--prefix` refers to the folder path to the root of the subtree repository

```
git subtree add --prefix=web weborigin master
```

pull normal commits made in `weborigin`

```
git subtree pull --prefix=web weborigin master
```

commits made in superproject to be backported

```
git commit -am "new changes to be backported"
```

checkout new branch for merging, set to track subtree repo

```
git checkout -b backport weborigin/master
```

cherry-pick backports

```
git cherry-pick -x --strategy=subtree master
```

push changes back to plugin source

```
git push weborigin backport:master
```

Comment: this is a really great answer, thanks, i have read officer doc, but it is unclear, this answer is really really clear for our fresh people for git who just like me. thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, submodules seems like a good fit for you.

Using submodules you would have one outer repository "projectname", and two inner repositories, "web" and "mobile".

Git submodules will create a strong version relationship between the outer and the inner repository. The outer repository will always point to a specific commit in the inner repository.

Comment: 'Git submodules will create a strong version relationship between the outer and the inner repository.' Could you explain this?