# git submodule add + not working + getting ssl server issue

Tags: git, ssl

I am trying to add a submodule `myapp` to my `admin` directory, bith of which are gits. But I keep getting `SSL certificate problem`. I have done `git config http.sslVerify false` to try and get it to work (but I am not fully sure why this should help, it worked when I wanted to push to a master `git push -u origin master`).**Any ideas?**

```
$ pwd
/c/Users/UserName/dir/admin
$ git submodule add ../myapp/
Cloning into 'myapp'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://myserver.com/gogs/user1/myapp/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Clone of 'https://myserver.com/gogs/user1/myapp' into submodule path 'myapp' failed
$ git config --list |grep ssl
http.sslverify=false
$
```

### EDIT1

Tried it again in a similar environment using [ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository) but something wrong with my access rights. **Any ideas?**

```
$ git submodule add ssh:../../lte_data_day_summary/
Cloning into 'sceal/lte_data_day_summary'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh: Temporary failure in name resolution
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Clone of 'ssh:../../lte_data_day_summary/' into submodule path 'sceal/lte_data_day_summary' failed
$ pwd
/c/Users/User Name/dir1/dir2/sceal
```

---

### EDIT2 - notes to self

global config

```
$ git config --global --list
user.email=you@example.com
http.sslverify=false
```

local config -- why is there 2? is this local and global?

```
$ git config --list | grep ssl
http.sslverify=false
http.sslverify=false
```

Comment: this might be what I need `git config --global http.sslverify false`. the `--global` is important here because I already had `http.sslverify=false`. but after settting it to global I get 2 `http.sslverify=false` now  `$ git config --list | grep ssl
http.sslverify=false
http.sslverify=false
`

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? We modified our TFS communincation to SSL and now we are seeing the same SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.  verifying SSL = false doesn't seem like a secure solution

Comment: no still using this. sorry not to help but it is secure enough for my current environment

Answer (score 0):

This might be the cause: [[PATCH] submodule: stop sanitizing config options - Jeff King](https://public-inbox.org/git/20160504080047.GA2436@sigill.intra.peff.net/)

```
The point of having a whitelist of command-line config
options to pass to submodules was two-fold:

  1. It prevented obvious nonsense like using core.worktree
     for multiple repos.

  2. It could prevent surprise when the user did not mean
     for the options to leak to the submodules (e.g.,
     http.sslverify=false).

For case 1, the answer is mostly "if it hurts, don't do
that". For case 2, we can note that any such example has a
matching inverted surprise (e.g., a user who meant
http.sslverify=true to apply everywhere, but it didn't).
```

The configuration might be dropped in order to avoid passing them to the submodules and causing unintended results (like cloning a certificate verifiable HTTPS submodule without verification).  A workaround is to set the `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` environment variable to the `git submodule` command:

```sh
# Set the environment variable is sufficient, no content is necessary
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY= git submodule add ...
```