# Git doesn't push folder src with inner folders

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I have the structure of the project: [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Aqr.png)

when i created repository on github and went step by step to push project. every file pushed normally except the folder src [repositrory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3BGW.png)

what should i do?

Comment: Huh? The icon shows it has nested directories. Just click on it.

Comment: Presumably you cannot click on it to see what's inside. This has happened to me before when I have accidentally committed a folder which is a git repo inside of my repo. If this is the case and it's a mistake you may be able to just remove the `.git/` directory inside the `src` folder as the contents will become part of the main repo anyway, or if not have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository.

Comment: @Michael i clicked and nothing happened. there is even no references

Comment: @roryrjb it didnt help:(

Comment: The icon indicates that it is a submodule.

Comment: See if it is coming in the un-tracked files while running 'git status'.
if yes then add the files in src separately and commit.

Comment: @jbialobr but it is not a submodule, how to correct it?

Comment: What does the following command return? `git submodule status`

Comment: @jbialobr fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'src'

Comment: Check .gitignore file, by mistake you added src in that file

Comment: @ThiruShetty no, it contains: /target/ /build/