# Can Git Plus in Atom have multiple Repo's

Tags: git, atom-editor

How do you get Atom to work with multiple repos?

The way it looks now looks like you have to have one main project file, and then you can link that to one repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I work with a git repository within another repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository)

Comment: No, that is about dependent projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple Project Folders who each have their own Git Repository. All you have to do is go to `File > Add Project Folder` or you can use the hotkey <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+A</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you'd like to use the submodules functionalities, right? There was also a post something similar to yours on the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository). Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have dependencies, they are totally independent projects that I would like to link to different repos. Atom seems to just see the one repo. I assume there is a way you can have multiple repos running. I just can't see it.

Comment: Sorry but now I don't understand. You want to achive this only from Atom, or are you also open to use Git bash for this?

Comment: I can do it outside Atom no problem. I am just trying to understand if Atom can work with multiple projects which have their own repo's at the same time. Again with independent repo's.

Comment: Well in that case maybe read through this link, otherwise I can't help you since Atom is not my primary IDE. 
https://discuss.atom.io/t/opening-multiple-git-projects/9117/4