# How to add an external repository into a new git repo

Tags: git, github

```
MainRepo
|
|--- repoABC
```

MainRepo is a git initiated repo.

```
MainRepo
|
| --- repoABC
|
| --- repoDEF (unclickable)
```

repoDEF is another git initialised repo moved inside MainRepo. After adding the repoDEF, I have git added and commited the mainRepo and then pushed to origin master .

See pic below: Only the first folder is accessible. How do I make the second folder accessible(clickable)

[image]

Comment: you may want to treat repoDEF as a submodule https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the history of the second repo, you can, locally in your repo, remove the [gitlink (SHA1 reference in the index of your main repo)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import#git-fast-import-Inlinedataformat), remove the `repoDEF/.git/` subfolder, then add again and push:

```
cd MainRepo
git rm --cached repoDEF     # no trailing /
rm -Rf repoDEF/.git
git add repoDEF
git commit -m "Import repoDEF sources"
git push
```

But if you do care about repoDEF history, then you need to add that second repo as a submodule.

```
cd MainRepo
git rm -r repoDEF 
git submodule add repoDEF /url/repoDEF
git commit -m "Reference repoDEF as a submodule"
git push
```