# Having both local and remote git repositories at the same time with different files included

Tags: git, git-submodules

I need a local repository for tracking my changes and a remote repository containing just some of these files.

I added a parent directory to the project to initialize a local repository and initialized another git in the project dir as another remote repository  and published it to GitHub.

.gitignore file of parent repo is empty but .gitignore in child excludes all fies except some specific ones. **Parent repository should not use .gitignore file of the child repo.**

**I need local repository to track all files and a remote repository to track just some of them.** The problem is that parent repository does not include anything inside the project.

I tried [this submodule solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository) but it creates a new folder for new repository instead of using existing one.

This is output of git add -A for parent repository:

```
 git add -A
warning: adding embedded git repository: Part Project Manager
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add <url> Part Project Manager
hint:
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint:
hint:   git rm --cached Part Project Manager
hint:
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

Comment: I didn't understand the problem.
1) You want the parent repo to track changes in parent and child directories?
2) What do you mean by ```parent repository does not include anything inside the project.```?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In fact I need local repository to track all files and a remote repository to track just some of them

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit, per submodule related question

You *can* nest repositories.  Here is an example—my Git version is slightly different from yours—on this particular machine it's currently 2.14.1—but I get the same new `git add` complaint and behavior, which requires a little initial trickery.

```
$ mkdir trepo
$ cd trepo
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo testing nested dirs > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 1eb37c9] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
```

The top level repository (`path/trepo`) now exists, with one commit in it.  The lone commit contains one file, `README`.

```
$ mkdir sub
$ cd sub
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .../trepo/sub/.git
$ echo this is a nested subdirectory > README
$ git add README 
$ git commit -m initial-sub
[master (root-commit) 943378a] initial-sub
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
```

The sub-repository now exists, also with one commit that contains one file named `README`.  If we now walk back up one level, we *can* convince Git to add the files inside `sub`.  However, as you found, a sufficiently modern Git—I'm not sure when this new behavior appeared—will, if we use `git add sub`, add `sub` as a *submodule*—well, add it as a *broken* submodule—rather than adding the files contained *within* `sub`.  So instead of `git add sub`, we will explicitly add the *files within `sub`*, for each such file (which is easy now as there is only one—remember, we want to *skip over* the `.git` directory and all its contents):

```
$ cd ..
$ git add sub/README
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   sub/README
```

Let's go ahead and commit this, then make another file in `sub` to see what happens:

```
$ git commit -m 'add sub/README'
[master a7fb248] add sub/README
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 sub/README
$ echo another test > sub/newfile
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        sub/newfile

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ (cd sub; git status)
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        newfile

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

So now that our `trepo/.git` repository is tracking files within `sub`, things work the way we might expect.

As I noted in comments, you *can* do all of this.  I have seen people try this method.  They usually end up unsatisfied.  Still, if it works for you, well, Git is a tool, not a solution; use it however you like!

(Note that when using submodules, the "top level" repository—Git calls this the *superproject*—will not contain the *same content* as the sub-repository.  Instead, each commit within the superproject will contain, in each commit, a special Git entry called a *gitlink* that records the *correct hash ID* that Git should `git checkout` in the submodule.  The submodule is a completely independent Git repository, all on its own, that you can use as a standalone project.  To use it *with* the superproject, you clone the superproject, then have Git use the superproject's `.gitmodules` file to know how to clone the submodule.  After that, each existing commit you extract *from* the superproject knows which commit to extract *in* the subproject, and each new commit you *make* in the superproject shall record the correct subproject commit.  It's up to you to make sure that those new superproject commits *do* record the correct subproject commit.)

#### Original answer below

---

This is not going to work the way you want.  Repositories don't hold files—well, not directly.  Repositories hold *commits*.  If you connect two repositories, what they will share is some set of *commits*.

Any given commit holds a snapshot (of files), so in that particular sense, a repository does hold files.  But it holds them one commit at a time.  In general, you `git checkout` an entire commit.  Let's call this commit `C1`.  This fills in your work-tree, and, very importantly, also fills in your index / staging-area.<sup>1</sup>  Your work-tree now has all the files that are in `C1`.

If you then switch from that commit to some other commit `C2`, Git *removes* any files that went with `C1` that are not in `C2`.  Your index and work-tree now match commit `C2`, not commit `C1`.

Pay no attention to `.gitignore` at this point, because it's largely irrelevant.  The set of *tracked* files, in a Git work-tree, are those files that are in the index.  They exist *in* the index *because* you extracted them from commit `C1` or `C2`, whichever it is that you checked out.  So those files are tracked, and any other files in your work-tree—however they may have arrived there—are untracked.

What `.gitignore` does is keep Git from *complaining about* the untracked files.  Normally, Git would whine at you, suggesting that you add them to the *next* commit you will make.  So if you have a bunch of build artifacts, for instance, you can list them in `.gitignore` and keep Git from whining.  As a pleasant side effect, this also means that `git add .` or `git add --all` won't *add* the untracked files—but their "untracked-ness" is a result of them *not being in the index right now*.

If you `git checkout` some other commit `C3` that has some other set of files in it, Git will *remove* from the work-tree any tracked file that *isn't* in `C3`, and add—to both index *and* work-tree—any files that are in `C3`.  (And, of course, it changes the *contents* of files that are in both commits, to whatever goes with `C3`.)  The files from `C3` are now, by definition, tracked.

Note: commits are uniquely identified by their hash IDs.  A repository either has the complete commit, or has nothing of that commit.  When you connect two repositories, Git's general process is to yank into itself *all* commits that the sending repository has, that the receiving repository lacks.<sup>2</sup>  That's *whole commits*, not files.  You then `git checkout` one of those commits to populate your index and your work-tree.  Branch names like `master` and `develop` mainly serve to identify one *particular* commit, namely the commit that Git is to use as the tip of that branch.

You *can* get what you want by playing fancy tricks with multiple index files.  But you'll need separate (unconnected) repositories with a single shared work-tree, which is tricky, and you'll need to commit everything separately *to* the two separate repositories, which is also tricky.  You also won't be able to use `.gitignore` files usefully (you'll need to use the per-repo `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` instead).  I don't recommend attempting this: I don't think I'd want to try to do it myself, and I know most of the dark corners of Git. :-)

---

<sup>1</sup>This index thing actually has *three* names, reflecting its three purposes: it (1) indexes the work-tree; (2) acts as a staging area in which you build up the *next* commit you will make; and (3) works as a *cache* to make `git commit` go very fast.

<sup>2</sup>This is an deliberate overstatement—the truth has to do with graph theory and [*reachability*](http://think-like-a-git.net/)—but it's good enough for an initial view.

Comment: Thanks. Can I have two repositories with different work-tree. I can commit them separately. How can I do this?

Comment: Two different repositories with two different work-trees is fine: that's what Git does "out of the box". Just create the two repositories in two separate file system locations and work with them.

Comment: OK. But Can I do this with nesting folders?

Comment: Sure: `dir` can have `dir/.git` and also `dir/sub` where `dir/sub` has `dir/sub/.git`. You will probably want to have `dir/.gitignore` say to ignore `dir/sub`.

Comment: NO, I want dir/.git repository to include all dir including dir/sub files and dir/sub/.git to include just dir/sub

Comment: Ah: you *can* do that, but I've never found anyone who likes the result.

Comment: I like to, but how? I tried but parent repository does not add files inside child repository. Which command should I use?

Comment: Your Git is probably seeing the `.git` in the subdirectory and thinking: *I'd best not add these, if anything this should be a submodule.* I remember Git used to behave that way at one time. I thought modern Git did not behave that way any more. Which Git version are you using?

Comment: git version 2.18.0.windows.1 

And I cannot add files in child repository. I added the error in the question