# GIT - Directory points to repository

Tags: git, symlink

Is it possible to create a directory inside a git repo that points to another repo?
Actually I want to create a symlink directory->repo and can't find a solution.

The problem is that in my project we are using multiple repos and I want to make it one repo only. For this matter, in order to leave things untouched and transparent for now, I just want to create something like a symlink.

Maybe I am missing something or it is indeed impossible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I work with a git repository within another repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository)

Comment: You should look at git submodules, as described in the URL given by @ThomasEdwards.