# Push changes to different branch as submodule from parent repo

Tags: git, branch, git-submodules

I have a branch `main` with another branch `child` in repo which is also a submodule of branch `main`.

```
main
- somefile
- somefolder
- child (S)
   -somefile
```

If I make changes to `child` submodule folder while working on `main` branch. How would i commit and push changes to `child` branch ?

Comment: A branch cannot be a submodule. Can you please use correct terminology? In the current form the question is not clear.

Comment: Yes it can. `git submodule add -b branchname...`

Comment: This means that the superproject **tracks the branch** of the submodule (instead of just tracking a commit). It doesn't mean the branch **is** a submodule.

Comment: And the answer that you're looking for is probably this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1811738/7976758. I.e., first you `cd` into the `child`, add, commit and push, then you `cd` back to the superproject, add, commit and push.