# Is there a way to import an external git repo in to a git project and still manage it from there

Tags: git

I have an **adminControl** project in a repository. This **adminControl** is an open source project and has the ability to perform all dynamic CRUD operations integrated in a beautiful UI and can fit into any project that runs PHP MySQL database depending on the parameters set.

Now i want to start creating **different websites**, say blog, media, company, schools, you name it. Each of **these websites** would be a git repo on their own and the each of them would have the **adminControl** project in them to manage all admin functions of **each website**.

Also i want all developers working on each of these projects to keep improving on the functionality and power of the **adminControl** project in their individual projects/repos/websites such that once they commit their changes, it'll also affect the main **adminControl** repo so that other project can pull the updates.

Is this possible ?

Comment: PHP and MYSQLI hae nothing to do with this question. Please keep you Tags relevent to the actual question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I work with a git repository within another repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository)

Comment: Look into Composer. Your adminControl would not be a part of your project’s history, but would be managed separately for both development and production. Thus pushing to production becomes a two-step process if you normally use a post-receive hook to checkout the remotes branch.

Comment: git submodules?

Comment: Let me check out Arun A S suggestion above