# Adding a private github repository inside another one

Tags: git, github

I have a private GitHub repository as follows

```
X
├── .git
└── (project files)
```

I am trying to add a private GitHub repository (project Y) into project X.

```
X
├── .git
├── (project files)
└── Y
    ├── .git
    └── (project files)
```

How can I add project Y to my current project X?

Comment: [Git Submodules?](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) *It often happens that while working on one project, you need to use another project from within it.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I work with a git repository within another repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have "two projects in one". But you can have two separate projects where the project at the top level folder will ignore a sub-folder. That folder will be the top level folder for the other project.

In project X, create a [gitignore](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore) file with an entry to ignore folder Y.

```
Y/
```

Project X, ignoring project Y.

```
X
├── .git
├── (project files)
├── .gitignore
└── Y
    ├── .git
    └── (project files)
```